# How to get non-decoded h264 stream from the webcam using ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg, video-streaming, webcam, h.264

I want to get the file which is non-decoded h264 format to use in another client application. I know how to stream to disk using below command from the docs.

**Example to encode video from /dev/video0:**

`ffmpeg -f v4l2 -framerate 25 -video_size 640x480 -i /dev/video0 output.mp4`

**High level Diagram**

This is typical producer and consumer problem -

```
Webcam  =============> ffmpeg to  video stream into file. (producer)                                    
                                       ^
                                       |
                                       |
Client ________________________________|
(consumer)
// reads only Non-decoded h264 format from a file.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this as solution

```
ffmpeg  -pix_fmt yuv420p -y -f v4l2 -vcodec h264  -i /dev/video0 out.h264
```

Comment: This in fact decodes the received stream and re-encodes it as H264.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
ffmpeg -f v4l2 -framerate 25 -video_size 640x480 -i /dev/video0 output.mp4 -c copy out.h264
```

`out.h264` is the received H264 bitstream, saved as a file.